# how to set request timeout in alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I tried it using NSURLSession but now I want to use Alamofire.

Answer (score 10):

This approach worked for me on swift 3

```
 let manager : SessionManager = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
            config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15
        let mgr = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: config)

        return mgr
    }()
```

Got it from https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#session-manager

Answer (score 4):

If you want a custom timeout, either set the value on your requests, or create a custom `URLSession` with a custom configuration: [alamofire documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#session-manager)

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10 // seconds
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

//OR

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "myApi.com/Api/login")!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 20)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    print(response)
    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call this function in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method in your AppDelegate.

```
func configureAlamofire() {
    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15 // in seconds
    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15 // in seconds
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120

manager.request("yourUrl", method: .post, parameters: ["parameterKey": "value"])
        .responseJSON {
            response in
            switch (response.result) {
            case .success:
                //do json stuff
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    //timeout here
                }
                print("\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")
                break
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a new version of **Alamofire**(above 5.0.0), write like this,

```
AF.sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120
AF.sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 120
```